# "Manage Client-Side Libraries" menu not appearing

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use the new Library Manager (LibMan) feature in Visual Studio 2017 (I'm using Version 15.7.1) but it is not appearing on either the project context menu or the *Project* menu.

I have tried various web projects but I can't see it for any of them. The only project type I haven't tried is ASP.NET Core 2.1 (I don't have the preview installed) but I can't find any docs that say it only works with ASP.NET Core 2.1

Here is a screenshot to prove it's not there:

[image: Solution Explorer with Context Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Visual Studio Community 15.7.5 references the "Library Manager" it looks like it is still in Preview and to be released with VS 15.8.

If you would like to use the Library Manager now it is fairly easy but there are a few work arounds right now to get it to install, probably a reason it is still in Preview.

[Clone or Download the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager)

**Note**: This requires the *Visual Studio extension development* Workload to be installed (Tools -> Get Tools and Features under "Other Toolsets").

According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/302) it will not install, before compiling the Extension open the project file for the LibraryManager.Vsix project

`[LibraryManagerDir]\src\LibraryManager.Vsix\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Vsix.csproj`

and update (line #30)

`<IsProductComponent>false</IsProductComponent>`

After 15.8 comes out this needs to be reset back to true to be able to install it.

Open the `LibraryManager.sln` and make sure to change the Configuration to `Release` and Build the Solution.

This will create a .vsix install file:

`[LibraryManagerDir]\src\LibraryManager.Vsix\bin\Release\Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.vsix`

Open `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.vsix` to launch the Visual Studio Installer.

Then you will have the `Add->Client Side Library` in your Context Menu.

Comment: This feature appeared when I upgraded to VS 15.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue.  I found the answer two it on another site, but for the life of me cannot find it for reference right now.  The easiest thing to do is to build it yourself and install it.  Works perfectly fine, I did it and now have the Manage Client Side libraries showing up.

1. Clone / download the Library Manager from GitHub. (https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/)
2. Build it in Visual Studio 2017
3. Run the .Vsix installer
4. Begin to use the Manage Client Side Libraries from the context menu or project menu.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this was your reference: 
https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/74

Comment: That looks different that what I had seen, but still it shows the same information.

Answer (score 1):

For me, in VS 2022 the context menu option appears but the dialog doesn't show. I found out that instead of right-clicking on project item i have to right-click on wwwroot item and then the dialog is shown